# Changing my notification code

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to get my notifications to work on a higher api than API22,

I'm struggling to get it to work,

If I can have someone tell me or show me what needs to be changed that would be great.

I get so close but it just fails every time.

Below is my code:

```
public class Utils {
    public static final int NOTIFY_ID1 = 1001;

    public static void notifyMessage(Context context, String msg, Activity activity){
        //Notification builder; 
        PendingIntent contentIntent = null;
        NotificationManager nm;
        // The NotificationManager object is required to send the notification
        nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Message object

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, activity.getClass());
        // PendingIntent.getActivity(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
        // Used to get a pending PendingIntent，Let the Intent start a new Activity to handle the notification
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


        //Defines the content information that appears in the notification bar

        int icon = R.drawable.chat;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, msg, when);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Call the system with sound

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; // Clicking the Clear button or clicking on the notification will automatically disappear

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notification.vibrate = new long[]{300, 500};
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "BluetoothChat", msg, contentIntent);


       /* // Customize the notification style we want to display in the status bar

        builder = new Notification(context);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)//Set the icon in the status bar（Small icon）
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.i5))//Drop the drop-down list inside the icon（Big icon） 　　　　　　　
            .setTicker("this is bitch!") //Set the status bar to display the information
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())//Set the time to occur
            .setAutoCancel(true)//The settings can be cleared
            .setContentTitle("This is ContentTitle")//Set the title in the drop-down list
            .setContentText("this is ContentText");//Set the context content

        */
        // Get the notification object you just created

        // Notification notification = builder.getNotification();//Get a Notification


        // send a notification message via NotificationManger
         // Parameter 1 notification ID, parameter 2 which notification to send

        nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID1, notification);
    }
}
```

When I add:

```html
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "BluetoothChat", msg, contentIntent);
```

I get the below error:

Error:(43, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo(Context,String,String,PendingIntent)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

My build gradle:

```html
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'app.name'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your issue, api level?

Comment: Where's your error log? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you can try  NotificationCompat. Example.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContent(remoteNotification)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC).
                    setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo)
                    .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(remoteNotification)
                    .setStyle(new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
```

Comment: it uses the support library.

Comment: did you try the Compat library i wrote

Comment: I did but the error im getting now is:

Error:(934, 11) error: non-static method notifyMessage(Context,String,Activity) cannot be referenced from a static context

I try and change it but then I get this error:

Error:(19, 48) error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context